# Codename One - ToastBar NullPointerException

Tags: nullpointerexception, codenameone, toast

If user clicks multiple times fast enough on `Button` which shows `ToastBar` - `ToastBar` throws `NullPointerException`.

**Stack**:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    (Code 1) at com.codename1.components.ToastBar.updateStatus(ToastBar.java:602)
    at com.codename1.components.ToastBar.access$300(ToastBar.java:84)
    at com.codename1.components.ToastBar$2.run(ToastBar.java:638)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.processSerialCalls(Display.java:1101)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.edtLoopImpl(Display.java:1045)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.invokeAndBlock(Display.java:1154)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.invokeAndBlock(Display.java:1191)
    at com.codename1.ui.AnimationManager.addAnimationAndBlock(AnimationManager.java:105)
    at com.codename1.ui.ComponentSelector.animateUnlayoutAndWait(ComponentSelector.java:3584)
    at com.codename1.ui.ComponentSelector.slideUpAndWait(ComponentSelector.java:1036)
    at com.codename1.components.ToastBar.setVisible(ToastBar.java:787)
    at com.codename1.components.ToastBar.updateStatus(ToastBar.java:502)
    at com.codename1.components.ToastBar.access$300(ToastBar.java:84)
    at com.codename1.components.ToastBar$2.run(ToastBar.java:638)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.processSerialCalls(Display.java:1101)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.edtLoopImpl(Display.java:1045)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.invokeAndBlock(Display.java:1154)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.invokeAndBlock(Display.java:1191)
    at com.codename1.ui.AnimationManager.addAnimationAndBlock(AnimationManager.java:105)
    at com.codename1.ui.Container.replaceComponents(Container.java:869)
    at com.codename1.ui.Container.replaceAndWait(Container.java:744)
    at com.codename1.components.ToastBar.updateStatus(ToastBar.java:602)
    at com.codename1.components.ToastBar.access$300(ToastBar.java:84)
    at com.codename1.components.ToastBar$2.run(ToastBar.java:638)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.processSerialCalls(Display.java:1101)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.edtLoopImpl(Display.java:1045)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.invokeAndBlock(Display.java:1154)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.invokeAndBlock(Display.java:1191)
    at com.codename1.ui.AnimationManager.addAnimationAndBlock(AnimationManager.java:105)
    at com.codename1.ui.Container.replaceComponents(Container.java:869)
    at com.codename1.ui.Container.replaceAndWait(Container.java:744)
    at com.codename1.components.ToastBar.updateStatus(ToastBar.java:602)
    at com.codename1.components.ToastBar.access$300(ToastBar.java:84)
    at com.codename1.components.ToastBar$Status.show(ToastBar.java:325)
    at com.codename1.components.ToastBar.showMessage(ToastBar.java:820)
    at com.codename1.components.ToastBar.showMessage(ToastBar.java:830)
    at com.codename1.components.ToastBar.showErrorMessage(ToastBar.java:858)
    (Code 2) at com.somesite.someapp.somepackage.DigitRoller.copyToClipboard(DigitRoller.java:122)
```

**(Code 1)**: *ToastBar.java*, line 602

```
c.label.getParent().replaceAndWait(c.label, newLabel, CommonTransitions.createCover(CommonTransitions.SLIDE_VERTICAL, true, 300));
```

**(Code 2)**: *DigitRoller.java*

```
protected void copyToClipboard () {
        Clipboard.copyString(sToken);
        ToastBar.showErrorMessage("Copied " + sToken, 1000);
    }
```

`copyToClipboard()` is invoked by this `ActionListener`:

```
btnCopy.addActionListener((e)-> {
            this.copyToClipboard();
        });
```

After displaying `Exception` details in `Dialog` the app freezes or stops animations by it's own decision.
Extremely simple way to crash application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a bug, I added a potential workaround for it [here](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/commit/99d9dc9441712a8af02b94c7d849f2dfa7cad8e6).